# JSF download file returns index.jsf

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces, jboss7.x

Im trying to achieve the same download file through JSF as described in those posts:
[JSF2 download file returns xhtml page source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514576/jsf2-download-file-returns-xhtml-page-source)
[How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-stream-a-file-download-in-a-jsf-backing-bean)
http://bharatonjava.wordpress.com/2013/02/01/downloading-file-in-jsf-2/
http://prabinhada.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-download-file-using-jsf.html

My problem is that I actually can download the file, but its name is just wrong ( on whichever browser ). 
It's a XML file I marshall in the download method but browser always receives a file index.jsf ( but mime type is set at text/xml and file size correct )

It runs on:

- Mojarra 2.1.7
- Richfaces 4.3.3.Final
- jboss-7.1.1.Final

Please see below if you spot any problem

```
    public void exportEDL() throws Exception {
    String name = this.file.getName();
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();      

    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

    BufferedOutputStream output = null;
    StringWriter sw = null;
    try {

        ...
        sw = new StringWriter();
        // edl is the jaxb i want to return as xml file
        marshaller.marshal(this.edl, sw);

        // Init servlet response.
        response.reset();
        response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);  
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        response.setContentLength( sw.getBuffer().length() );
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename\"" + name + "\"");
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        output.write(sw.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

        // Finalize task.
        sw.flush();
        output.flush();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {    
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage( FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, e.getMessage() );  
        facesContext.addMessage("Error", msg); 
        return;
    } finally {
        // Gently close streams.
        IOUtil.close(sw);
        IOUtil.close(output);
        clearUploadData();
    }

    // Inform JSF that it doesn't need to handle response.
    facesContext.responseComplete();
   // facesContext.renderResponse();
   // facesContext.release();
}
```

I tried with something else than a XML marshalling without better results.
Have you guys manage to download a file with correct name + extension?

It's a commandButton in the view:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{fileUploadBean.exportEDL()}"
```

Thanks!

Comment: response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + name + "\""); // add a = sign does the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a `=`, I think this would be right:

```java
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + name + "\"");
```

or just

```java
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + name);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you are right I managed to mess up a copy paste :/